# cuda thrust: selective copying and resizing results

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am copying items selectively between two thrust device arrays using `copy_if` as follows:

```
thrust::device_vector<float4> collated = thrust::device_vector<float4> 
                       original_vec.size());
thrust::copy_if(original_vec.begin(), original_vec.end(),
                collated.begin(), is_valid_pt());
collated.shrink_to_fit();
```

The `is_valid_pt` is implemented as:

```
struct is_valid_kpt
{
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const float4 x)
    {
        return x.w >= 0;
    }
};
```

Now after running this code, I was expecting the size of the `collated` vector to be much less than the original array but they are still the same size.

Comment: Once again, a question with a vague problem description and no repro case. How many more times will we have to ask? (and the key output from `copy_if` is the iterator it returns, why aren't you using it?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thrust doesn't resize vectors as part of any algorithm call.  The size of vectors going into a thrust algorithm will be exactly the size of those vectors coming out of the algorithm.

[shrink_to_fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/) also has no impact on a vector's **size**, but it may impact the capacity, which has to do with allocation.

If you want to reduce the size of `collated` to the actual number of elements that were copied into it, you will need to use [the return value of the `copy_if` function](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#gafd4cd96b998ad2b3c336be1e24dc1f67), to compute its size, and then do a resize.

Something like this:

```
size_t my_size = thrust::copy_if(original_vec.begin(), original_vec.end(), collated.begin(), is_valid_pt()) - collated.begin();
collated.resize(my_size);
```

Comment: Isn't the return an iterator? So that the valid output lies between `collated.begin()` and the return value of the `copy_if`?

Comment: Yes.  Scroll the code box to the right.  I am subtracting `collated.begin()` to produce a size.   I didn't say the return value *is* the size, I said use the return value to compute a size.

Comment: Apologies, I am reading this on a mobile device where the horizontal scroll bars don't work.